# Compilling C++ in visual studio code on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to compile a very simple code. I put in tasks.json configuration copied from
[here](https://medium.com/@jerrygoyal/run-debug-intellisense-c-c-in-vscode-within-5-minutes-3ed956e059d6).

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build & debug file",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "-o",
        "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "${file}"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "build & run file",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": [
        "-o",
        "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "${file}"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I build (ctrl+shift+b) I get errors:

> usr/bin/ld:/home/username/LinuxProjects/FirstCppProject/.vscode/tasks.json:
>   file format not recognized; treating as linker script
>   /usr/bin/ld:/home/username/LinuxProjects/FirstCppProject/.vscode/tasks.json:1:
>   syntax error collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status The terminal
>   process terminated with exit code: 1

I don't understand what's wrong with the json.

Comment: Have you checked the end of line for this file?

Comment: what exactly should I check?

Comment: Check that your end of line is Unix and not Windows. Have you downloaded the file from Windows, or Linux?

Comment: I copy-pasted it from the site via firefox in Ubuntu

Comment: try to run dos2linux on the file (converts end of line from windows to linux)

Comment: I've checked the file in ghex. It ends with "0A"

Comment: That's the case for all end of lines. What about the character before? Is it `0d`?

Comment: No. Sorry, I wanted to say that it is without '0d' before. 
I have '7D 0A', '7D' is '}'

Comment: I found that I had to change the line ending to CRLF from LF. I did this in the bottom right corner of the screen, where it lists the cursor position, tab size, encoding type, the line ending , code type and envionment type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is compiling the currently active file, so you have to ensure you have the intended source file is active (i.e. open and in view). If you run this command when the task.json file is active, it will attempt to compile the task.json file.